DistinctCount with multiple time intelligence filter
Is there a way to reduce my syntax into single Calculate DistinctCount?
My query
CALCULATE( (
    CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales Invoice'[Customer Code]),
            DATESBETWEEN(DimDate[Date], EDATE(MIN(DimDate[Date]), -2), EDATE(MAX(DimDate[Date]), -1))
    ) = 0 
    &&
    CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales Invoice'[Customer Code]),
            DATESBETWEEN(DimDate[Date], EDATE(MIN(DimDate[Date]), -0), EDATE(MAX(DimDate[Date]), -0))
    ) = 1
)

I want to check between multiple time intelligence filters like, Customer who have last record 3 months ago and have no record 2 months ago.
Is there a query something like this??
CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales Invoice'[Customer Code]),
            DATESBETWEEN(DimDate[Date], EDATE(MIN(DimDate[Date]), -2), EDATE(MAX(DimDate[Date]), -1)) = 0 &&
            DATESBETWEEN(DimDate[Date], EDATE(MIN(DimDate[Date]), 0), EDATE(MAX(DimDate[Date]), 0)) = 1
    )


Try this measure:
Measure = 
VAR thisDate = TODAY()
RETURN
CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales Invoice'[Customer Code]),
            (DimDate[Date] > EDATE(thisDate, -3) && EDATE(thisDate, -1) > DimDate[Date] ) // Include 3 months ago from today's date
            && NOT (DimDate[Date] > EDATE(thisDate, -2) && EDATE(thisDate, -1) > DimDate[Date] ) // Exclude 2 months ago from today's date
)


Thank you for your response @Nick, but it didn't work. By the way I have a 'Sales Invoice'[Date] on my Sales Invoice table.

Can you please provide some sample data and what the output of this measure was against your data?

Actually this query is working. It just don't give me the value in my grand total..
IF(
DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales Invoice'[Customer Code]),
DATESBETWEEN(DimDate[Date], EDATE(MIN(DimDate[Date]), -2), EDATE(MAX(DimDate[Date]), -1))
) = 0
&&
CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales Invoice'[Customer Code]),
DATESBETWEEN(DimDate[Date], EDATE(MIN(DimDate[Date]), -0), EDATE(MAX(DimDate[Date]), -0))
) = 1,
1,
0,
)

Finally found the answer.
Customer with Sales 3 months ago but not in the last 2 months =
VAR Last2Months =
CALCULATETABLE (
VALUES ( Sales[CustomerKey] ),
DATESBETWEEN (
Dates[Date],
EDATE ( MIN ( Dates[Date] ), -2 ),
EDATE ( MAX ( Dates[Date] ), 0 )
)
)
VAR _3MonthsAgo =
CALCULATETABLE (
VALUES ( Sales[CustomerKey] ),
DATESBETWEEN (
Dates[Date],
EDATE ( MIN ( Dates[Date] ), -3 ),
EDATE ( MAX ( Dates[Date] ), -3 )
)
)
RETURN
COUNTROWS ( EXCEPT ( _3MonthsAgo, Last2Months ) )

Credit to DAXJutsu
